# What does "There are problems and -y was used without --force-yes" mean?

Tags: apt

I'm having this command automatically generated and run by Puppet:

```
sudo /usr/bin/apt-get -q -y -o DPkg::Options::=--force-confold install 2klic-gateway=2.10.5
```

When run it returns:

```
There are problems and -y was used without --force-yes
```

I'm trying to understand this error message. The GPG key of the provider for the package is valid, and there is no problem manually running the command without the `-y` flag.

Why does Ubuntu force me to either use `--force-yes` (which can be dangerous) or manually enter `y`, without using the `-y` flag?

Comment: Usually you can not use -y for installing third party packages. That's why it wants you to use --force-yes in addition to allow the -y even for third party packages.

Comment: @derHugo there is no problem installing third party packages with `-y`, I can verify this because I'm doing it. This error only occurs when I'm using `-y` while downgrading the version of a package.

Comment: Hm I always get similar errors installing e.g. webmin with -y option and it always says like "-y is not permitted on third party packages" so I thought...

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I found anytime a package is downgraded it must be done so manually or with `--force-yes`. This was intended by the makers of the `apt` package.

If you're using `apt` version 1.1 you can also use `--allow-downgrades`. Before 1.1 `--force-yes` is the only option.

`Apt` version 1.1 also added `--allow-remove-essential` and `--allow-change-held-packages`, which may be useful for anyone who stumbles upon this question.

*From man page: http://manpages.ubuntu.com/manpages/zesty/man8/apt-get.8.html*

```
   --allow-downgrades
       This is a dangerous option that will cause apt to continue without
       prompting if it is doing downgrades. It should not be used except
       in very special situations. Using it can potentially destroy your
       system! Configuration Item: APT::Get::allow-downgrades. Introduced
       in APT 1.1.

   --allow-remove-essential
       Force yes; this is a dangerous option that will cause apt to
       continue without prompting if it is removing essentials. It should
       not be used except in very special situations. Using it can
       potentially destroy your system! Configuration Item:
       APT::Get::allow-remove-essential. Introduced in APT 1.1.

   --allow-change-held-packages
       Force yes; this is a dangerous option that will cause apt to
       continue without prompting if it is changing held packages. It
       should not be used except in very special situations. Using it can
       potentially destroy your system! Configuration Item:
       APT::Get::allow-change-held-packages. Introduced in APT 1.1.

   --force-yes
       Force yes; this is a dangerous option that will cause apt to
       continue without prompting if it is doing something potentially
       harmful. It should not be used except in very special situations.
       Using force-yes can potentially destroy your system! Configuration
       Item: APT::Get::force-yes. This is deprecated and replaced by
       --allow-downgrades, --allow-remove-essential,
       --allow-change-held-packages in 1.1.
```